# How to obtain the length of an online audio file in java

Tags: java, html

How can I obtain the file length from an HTTP URL?

I am creating a bot for an app and I have a music player for that bot.
When you type `!stream http://example/audio.mp3` the bot connects to your voice channel and starts playing the song. I need to make the bot disconnect when the song has ended, and for that I need the length of that audio file from the website.

Edit: what I need is the length of the audio file preferably in seconds so I can determin after what ammount of time to stop the connection. Also the bot is for discord and I use an external api: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA I hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: How are you obtaining the audio file? Are you streaming it back through an `InputStream`? Do you stream back the whole thing before you play it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so JDA. Thanks for the clarification.

I am not an expert in JDA, but found out the followings:

- check this audio example: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/src/examples/java/AudioExample.java locate the usage of the player instance of FilePlayer
- find the javdoc for FilePlayer: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/audio/player/FilePlayer.java
- notice that it has an isPlaying() method.

Now you can simply periodically check if the audio is still played by checking isPlaying periodically.

---

**To dig out the length of the audio**

You can see that FilePlayer extends Player.java.

- check the source of Player java https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/audio/player/Player.java
- you can see the usage of AudioInputStream in the setAudioSource method
- get the javadoc of AudioInputStream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html
- notice getFrameLength which returns the size of the stream. You can see in Player as the audio is actually getting resampled to 48KHz, so you know that 48000 frames mean 1 second. Multiply the result of getFrameLength by 48000 to obtain the length in seconds.

*Note that it won't really help in your case, unless you're tracking the playback progress separately, so this solution is unnecessarily complicated.*

Comment: Thank you, gonna try that when I'll have some time.

Answer (score 0):

Length of audio? In bytes? In seconds? there are plenty of good answers!

**Stop when the download is over**

You seem to access to a static mp3 file, which is loaded via http protocol. Now you don't need to *do* anything, since once all the data from that mp3 file has been received by your computer, the connection is over.

Check this: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url find the **while** loop which goes until there is data from the server. Then the while loop exits when there is no data.

So to put it short: once inputStream.read(buffer) returns -1, there is no more data, so receiving your mp3 is over.

**Stop when the playback is over**

It is a separate question if you want to detect when *playback* of the mp3 is over. For that, you need to post some of your code, and explain what mp3 decoder/sound playback libraries are you using.

For example Un4seen development's BASS framework offers both callbacks, reading out of the total time during decoding and reading the current time of the playback too. Doing the same with Java Audio API is not that trivial - since the API writes to the DMA buffers, and the last half a second plays after all the data has been sent.

There are a lot more frameworks out there to handle audio and mp3 decoding, therefore giving a clear answer to your question is not possible without further input :)

Comment: "I want is to make the bot disconnect when the song has ended" ; I think that separate question was the one asked.

Comment: downloading of the song has ended, or playback of the song has ended, that is the question. There are a few ways to download or to stream the song, and a lot more ways to play it back. For example Un4seen development's BASS framework offers both callbacks, reading out of the total time during decoding and reading the current time of the playback too. Doing the same with Java Audio API is not that trivial - since the API writes to the DMA buffers, and the last half a second plays _after_ all the data has been sent.

Comment: Considering the nearly good grammar of the question, I'm quite confident "the song has ended" means "the song has ended playing". OP's clarification would still be welcome, but maybe should you include some of that insightful comment in your answer?

Comment: No, I have nothing wrong with the grammar. I tried to escape from answering the impossible question of "how to detect end of the playback of my framework, I don't tell which one I am using". I've edited the answer to reflect that there is not enough info in the question to answer this second interpretation of the challenge.

Comment: Without clarification from OP, it definitely sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Yup when the song has ended playing was what I meant. Sorry if was unclear but the download can end before the song ends playing so that won't be good.